# Shell script: Variable inside nested quotes

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to write a shell script that `cat`s some file and runs `awk` to extracts lines that contain a date that I pass into the script as an argument.

The script will be invoked like `/my_script.sh 2021-01-01`

Here are the contents of `/my_script.sh`.

```
DATE=$1
cat /myfile | awk -F , '$12 == "$DATE" { print } '
```

Note that $12 corresponds to the date column that I care about.

When I run this and look at the process with ps aux, I see that the command being run is literally:

> awk -F , $12 == "$DATE" { print }

How can I embed the DATE variable inside the double quotes which is inside the single quotes?

Comment: Also `awk` is perfectly capable of reading from files itself, without needing them spoon-fed to it by `cat`. So don't use `cat somefile | awk ...`, use `awk ... somefile.

Comment: I think it could be like this `cat /myfile | awk -v DATE="$DATE" -F , '$12 == DATE'`

Comment: @GordonDavisson is fine, only use by this `awk -v DATE="$DATE" -F , ...other-awk-parameter /myfile`

Comment: @VictorLee regarding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68045314/shell-script-variable-inside-nested-quotes#comment120267941_68045314 - no, `$12 == "$DATE"` tests if `$12` is literally the 5-character string `$DATE`, not the contents of the variable `DATE`.

Comment: yes， I can’t edit the first comment so i delete that.